# Joining two tables but getting no result

Tags: mysql, sql-server, wampserver

Table1

| Move1 | Move2 |
| --- | --- |
| Fire | Ice |
| Grass | Fire |
| Ice | Grass |

Table2

| Move | Power |
| --- | --- |
| Fire | 40 |
| Grass | 30 |
| Ice | 20 |

I have these two tables, but when I run this SQL statement in WAMPServer, I get no rows returned:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1, Table2
    INNER JOIN Table1 as Hello ON Hello.move1 = Table2.move
    INNER JOIN Table1 as Meow ON Meow.move2 = Table2.move
```

Both tables are under the same database, so I can't see my error. I want it to return something like...

Table1

| Move1 | Move2 | Move | Power | Move | Power |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Fire | Ice | Fire | 40 | Ice | 20 |
| Grass | Fire | Grass | 30 | Fire | 40 |
| Ice | Grass | Ice | 20 | Grass | 30 |

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
select
  m.move1,
  m.move2,
  m1.move,
  m1.power,
  m2.move,
  m2.power
from
  table1 m
  join table2 m1 on m1.move = m.move1
  join table2 m2 on m2.move = m.move2
```

You can test this in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e08db/1)

Answer (score 3):

You're code is wrong in several ways, you should learn how to use SQL joins ([This](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) is a nice, basic explanation)

As far as solving your problem, try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 t2_m1
  ON table1.move1 = t2_m1.move INNER JOIN t2_m2
  ON table1.move2 = t2_m2.move
```